Question about Finding the order of the quotient ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{19}]/I$
I have a doubt concerning the problem mentioned at Finding the order of the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]/I$.
In this post it's shown that $$
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]/I\cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^{2}+19,4,2+2X)
$$
But right after mentioning this, Peter concludes that $$
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]/I\cong(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})[X]/(X^{2}-1,2+2X)
$$
What happened here? It seems like Peter moved the "4" upwards and put it next to the $\mathbb Z$ in the numerator

Define a map, $\Phi:\dfrac{\Bbb{Z}[X]}{\langle X^{2}+19,4,2+2X \rangle} \to  \dfrac{\Bbb{Z_4}[X]}{\langle X^{2}+19,2+2X \rangle}$ by $\Phi(f(x) + \langle X^{2}+19,4,2+2X \rangle) = \bar{f}(x) + \langle X^{2}+19,2+2X \rangle$. This $\Phi$ is a ring isomorphism.
Also if we define $\Phi: \Bbb{Z}[X] \to  \dfrac{\Bbb{Z_4}[X]}{\langle X^{2}+19,2+2X \rangle}$ by $\Phi(f(x)) = \bar{f}(x) + \langle X^{2}+19,2+2X \rangle$, where $\bar{f} = f \bmod{4}$. Then, $\Phi$ is a ring homomorphism. Now calculate $\ker \Phi = \{f \in \Bbb Z[X]: \bar{f} = a(X)(X^2+19)+b(X)(2+2X), \text{where}, a(X),b(X) \in \Bbb Z[X]\}
\\ =\{f \in \Bbb Z[X]: f(X) -4c(X) = a(X)(X^2+19)+b(X)(2+2X), \text{where}, a(X),b(X),c(X) \in \Bbb Z[X]\}
\\ =\{f \in \Bbb Z[X]: f(X) = 4c(X) + a(X)(X^2+19)+b(X)(2+2X), \text{where}, a(X),b(X),c(X) \in \Bbb Z[X]\}
\\ = \langle 4,X^2+19,2+2X \rangle$

This generalizes in a nice way.  Note that $\langle x^2+19, 2+2x, 4 \rangle = \langle x^2+19, 2+2x \rangle + \langle 4 \rangle$.  Now, if we want to quotient by a sum of ideals, we can essentially quotient by one at a time.  Namely
$$R/(I+J)\simeq (R/I)/[J]$$
where $[J]$ is the image of $J$ in $R/I$.  If we've got a finitely generated ideal, this lets us quotient out by the ideal by quotienting out be each generator one at a time.  If you think of quotienting as imposing relations where all the elements in the ideal become equivalent to zero, this should make a certain amount of sense.
Regardless, in this case, because $\mathbb Z/\langle 4 \rangle \simeq \mathbb Z_4$, the computation follows from the above result.
